# Button for Submitting to Database Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to insert data to a row in a sqlite database table by filling a form and it has error when I click the submit button. Here's the piece of code and the logcat

```
public void callDialogConfirmation(){

    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(Form.this);
      confirm.setTitle("Please Confirm");

      confirm.setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String inputanSavings = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String tglmsk = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
            editor.putString("sharedString1", inputanSavings);
            editor.putString("sharedString2", tglmsk);

            editor.commit();
             String inputSalary = salary.getText().toString();
             dbHelper.createIncome("Routine Income",inputSalary);
                      Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Form.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(openStartingPoint);


         }});
```

and here's the method to insert the data

```
       public long createIncome(String l, String n) {


    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(RLPE, l);
    initialValues.put(RNPE, n);
    initialValues.put(RBPE, m);   // The m is the current date with Calendar library

    return mDbP.insert(INCOME_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}
```

Here's the error I'm getting as soon I click the "submit" button

```
            07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971): java.lang.NullPointerException
            07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at     com.diarykeuanganmahasiswa.dkm.Form$1.onClick(Form.java:64)
            07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
            07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
           07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
           07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
          07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
          07-21 22:00:39.234: E/AndroidRuntime(971):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone knows what seems to be the problem? Please help, thanks

Comment: Your onClick is dereferencing a null pointer on line 64.  Which line is that?

Comment: it's the `dbHelper.createIncome("Routine Income",inputSalary);` Any idea why it's null? There's nothing wrong on the inputsalary isn't it?

Comment: Its the dbHelper that's null.  Where are you creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your your storing your data from the UI in shared preferences and attempting to retrieve them from ContentValues.  In your UI you should put your values into the Content Values and pass that to the insert.  The retrieval of those value in the insert method should then be able to get them properly. Content Values is a Name Value pair, i.e. name of the column and value of the column.

In your UI activity:

```
ContentValues cv;
...
//in your onClick method
cv = new ContentValues();
...
cv.put("inputanSavings", inputanSavings);
... etc, for each column.
```

Uri rowURI = cr.insert(yourURI, cv);
   // cv should have the NvP (Name Value Pair) for each of your columns.

If needed you can put your content values into a bundle and have the async task or content provider extract them, if you have a lot of other steps to accomplish before the insert.

Hope this helps. Please mark this as the correct answer if it works for you.

Have a great day.